# How do I navigate to a new page in windows 8 metro apps after the sound is finished playing?

Tags: c#, windows-8, navigation, mediaelement

I'm using the following code to play sound on a button click.

```
public class AudioHelper
    {
        public async static void playButtonClick()
        {
            MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();
            StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Audios");
            StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("buttonClick.m4a");
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            snd.Play();
        }
    }
```

I called the code from the button click event using the following codes:

```
 private void btnFlashCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AudioHelper.playButtonClick();
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LevelSelection));
        }
```

since the playButtonClick is async, the page navigate to the LevelSelection page before the audio start playing.  How do I make it so that the audio play first then the page navigate? Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @htcdmrl  I was able to figure out how to do this.  As I mentioned in the comment, in order for the MediaEnded event to fire, the MediaElement has to be in the visual tree.  I added the following code in the xaml and modify the code slightly to get it to work.

I added the following code to XAML:

```
 <Frame HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,742,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MediaElement x:Name="me"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="20,742,0,-74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.359,-0.219"/>
        </Frame>
```

Added the following codes to MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            me.MediaEnded += me_MediaEnded;
        }

        void me_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LevelSelection));
        }
```

and change playButtonclick and btnFlashCard_Click to the following:

```
private void btnFlashCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            playButtonClick();
        }

        public async void playButtonClick()
        {


            StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Audios");
            StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("buttonClick.m4a");
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            me.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);

            me.Play();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add media ended event to your media element;

```
MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();
snd.MediaEnded += snd_MediaEnded;
```

Then add your event;

```
void snd_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    snd.Stop();
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LevelSelection));
}
```

Comment: I added the MediaEnded event as you showed above but the MediaEnded Event never fired. Any idea?

Comment: I figure out what was wrong.  As it turned out that in order for the event to fire, the MediaEnded has to be in the visual Tree.  In order for me to be able to do this i have to add frame with mediaelement in it in the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Use Event MediaElement.MediaEnded Event:

```
private void btnFlashCard_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(LevelSelection));
}
```